# Help with tables and multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm trying to create a table with the following structure:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
    \begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l|l| }
        \hline
        \rowcolor{gray!50}
        \textbf{Posición} & \textbf{Función del Campo} & \textbf{Código Descripción} &\textbf{Valores} \\
        \hline
        1 & Indicador de Centro & Indica que se trata de un centro & C\\
        \hline
        2 & Tipo de Centro & \multirow{2}{*}{Indica que tipo de centro se trata} & Z para Centros Zonales & I para Centros Intermedios\\
        \hline
        3 - 5 & Localización & Localización del Centro & Tres primeras de ubicación pej: Valencia: VAL\\
        \hline
        6 & Numero de Centro & Ordenación de los punto de presencia & Ascendente dependiendo de fecha de instalación\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Nomenclatura Centros Zonales e Intermedios}
    \label{table:Centros}
 \end{table}
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

How do I fix it so that not only does the multirow works how in the correct place but also the cable doesn't overflow from the page.

Thank you in advance,

PS. Open to suggestions about colours

Comment: your example (please always make full document) produces `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.` so the pdf output that you show is arbitrary, you should look at the log not the pdf after an error. I couldn't work out the intended location of `I para Centros Intermedios` ?

Comment: Just updated the first image to make it more clear. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This still needs some work to be done, but you may start with:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=--}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{>{\RaggedRight\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{\dimexpr( \textwidth-5\arrayrulewidth-8\tabcolsep)/4}|}}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{gray!50}
        \textbf{Posición} & \textbf{Función del Campo} & \textbf{Código Descripción} &\textbf{Valores} \\
        \hline
        $1$ & Indicador de Centro & Indica que se trata de un centro & C\\
        \hline
        $2$ & Tipo de Centro & Indica que tipo de centro se trata & Z para Centros Zonales  I para Centros Intermedios\\
        \hline
        \numrange{3}{5} & Localización & Localización del Centro & Tres primeras de ubicación pej: Valencia: VAL\\
        \hline
        6 & Numero de Centro & Ordenación de los punto de presencia & Ascendente dependiendo de fecha de instalación\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Nomenclatura Centros Zonales e Intermedios}\label{table:Centros}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

I was not too sure about where to put everything (see Mr. Carlisle's comment). The thickness of the vertical lines still needs to be subtracted (done already in edit, trick taken from David) here. I would omit those lines completely.

The first columns could be made narrower of course. Just edit the column definitions as you please. All those topics are treated a lot on this homepage here.

[image]

Comment: I guess you were first, I'll delete mine:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As thanks for that noble gesture I have stolen your much cooler `\dimexpr(...)` :-)

Comment: Just updated the first image to show how I would like the table to look in my document.

Comment: @Neptune the last column is in vertical mode so you could use (for example) blank line \hrule blank line between the two paragraphs starting Z para and I para...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle unfortunately that doesn't work :(